# Is there Bank account good for freelancers?

Tags: taxes, accounting, foreign-markets

The idea is to create a bank account having the residence in a different country from the one the bank is based on. So international clients accepted in this bank would be the right thing.

I've heard about one placed in **Sweden** but I cannot find it anywhere. They make very easy to manage international payments and taxes.

Does anyone have some information about?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but I've heard good things about the the [Estonian e-residency](https://e-estonia.com/e-residents/about/) in regards to e-businesses and banks.

Answer (score 0):

[Verksamt.se](https://www.verksamt.se/en/web/international/starting/planning-your-start) offers an excellent guide to what Swedish bankers, investors and authorities look for in a business plan.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Uphold](https://uphold.com). You can transfer between Uphold accounts for free and there are free currency conversions while in your Uphold account. You can find out more about the services [here](https://uphold.com/en/what-we-do/individuals).